# Extend Laravel Session Timelife

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel application which has a session lifetime of 5 minutes. So i have managed to prompt the user with a countdown timer on the last minute of 5 minutes, if there is no activity for 4 minutes. So i am stuck on extending the session lifetime after the user interact with the countdown dialogue box, can you please help me extend the session lifetime without refreshing the current page.

Comment: use mouse event for problem solving

Comment: I get that, but how will i extend session lifetime after i have prompted a user without refreshing my blade? I have observed that a session lifetime is set back to its initial time when i refresh my blade page.

Comment: When user move his/her mouse point then call a function that initial your session time

Comment: Okay... I have done that but when i navigate or request a new page, it redirects me to a login page which means the session is expired. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes understand?

Comment: How then should i solve the issue?

Comment: so, you have a page with a countdown for the remaining time before session expire, and on mousemove you want to reset that counter both on the page and on the server?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes

Comment: and on mouse move, running a ajax request does not work as solution?

Comment: yes it does not work. The only thing that is working is when i refresh the page.